# Jax-RS request mapping to operation with @DefaultValue and @QueryParam

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, restful-url

I wonder how jax-rs (or Jersey as implementation) maps the client request to the actual operation while using `@DefaultValue` with `@QueryParam`.

Assume that you have the following operations in the resource, one returns all the resources and the other returns all with a custom view;

```
@Path(/v1)
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path(/my-resource)
    public Response getAllResources(){
       ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path(/my-resource)
    public Response getAllResources(@QueryParam("view") @DefaultValue("simple") String view){
       ...
    }
}
```

In this case, if I call the service as `/v1/my-resource`, how the mapping would work internally and which operation is picked?

I appreciate if there's any explanation for this in the specification.

Thanks,

Tugcem.

Comment: With Jersey, You'll get a ModelValidationException error on startup as the two methods are ambiguous. The application will fail to start. Jersey can't differentiate resource methods based on query parameters (or just parameters in general)

Answer (score 0):

As Paul correctly mentioned, you should not have more than 1 method for the same resource and web method (and acceptable media type). That's true for JAX-RS in general, not just some implementation. See JAX-RS spec:

> 3.7.2 Request Matching
>   ...
>   If there is more than one maximum element, implementations
>   SHOULD report a warning and select one of these types in an implementation dependent manner.